# how to change background color to multiple colors as an animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a function that changes the background colour to various colours(as an animation). I have used for loop to change hexadecimal colour code. But only I can see the changing it into one colour.

```js
function changeColors() {
    var colors = 000100;

    for (var i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
        colors += i;
        var x = (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + colors);
    }
}

changeColors();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #80eb80;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not going to work for multiple reasons.  As an alternative, have a look at css color transitions here: [CSS Tricks - Using Multi-Step Animations and Transitions](https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. This can be easily done by using CSS animation.

```css
@keyframes bg {
  0% { background: #000000; }
  25% { background: #000099; }
  50% { background: #009999; }
  75% { background: #999999; }
  100% { background: #000000; }
}
body {
  background: #000;
  animation: bg 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Just change the colors to whatever you want. Working example: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/bGaYRVz?editors=0100

If you need to start the animation dynamically by JavaScript, just put the animation part to a CSS class and toggle the class.

---

And just some additional notes. The reason that your code is not working is because your for loop is synchronous. The entire for loop ends immediately, maybe a few milliseconds. Browsers are smart enough to execute the JavaScript at once, and then re-paint the screen only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeHex() {
  let hex = '#';
  const hexValues = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F'];
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length);
    hex += hexValues[index];
  }

  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = hex;
}

setInterval(() => changeHex(), 1500);
```

You can check it by this URL [here](https://js-8xamkc.stackblitz.io/)